# increase characters visible in diff -y columns

Tags: bash, diff

Is it possible to increase the amount of characters visible per line, per column when running `diff -y <fooA.txt> <fooB.txt)`? I have files with very long names and it is unclear which ones are being compared when the names are truncated in the columns.

ex.
`8d14a361aefb7796de07e9ef4aa5d2f4  2014_141_1_1__Studs_Place_c |    77831755d1f1db1c726d0964c807b74b  2014_141_1_1__Studs_Place_c`

Comment: This is not a bash question in any respect -- you'd have the exact same behavior if you were invoking `diff` from any other shell, or without a shell involved at all.

Comment: (Also, if you're putting code in backticks, that formatting implies that it's literal -- thus, that any `<`s are, in the context of bash, redirection operators. If what you mean is to use a placeholder, consider making it a placeholder in a way that's still valid shell syntax, ie. `diff -y "$file1" "$file2"`)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the the formatting help! @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man diff`:

> ```
>    -W NUM  --width=NUM
>          Output at most NUM (default 130) print columns.
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.